# Existence of holomorphic function from unit disc to itself.

Tags: complex-analysis

Does there exists a holomorphic function from open unit disc to itself s.t. $f(1/2)=-1/2$ and $f'(3/4)=1$?
I think the answer is 'Yes' as $f(z)=z-1$ satisfies these conditions. Kindly correct me if I am wrong in interpretation of $f(z)$ which maps $D$ to $D$.
Edit: If I use linear transformation f(z)=az+b ;|a|≦1 &|a|+|b|≦1 to seek the existence of such a function from unit disk to itself, I do not get f(z) due to voilation of |a|+|b|≦1.Does it mean that such function cannot exist? As I know a linear mapping completely characterizes any transformation from disc to disc.

Comment: Well, $0 ∈ \mathbf D$, but $f(0) = 0 - 1 ∈ \mathbf D$?

Comment: ok..got it k.stm. Is it fine to say that f(z)=az+b with |a|≦1 and |a|+|b|≦1?

Comment: k.stm. Cann't we use linear function f(z)=az+b, |a|≦1 and |a|+|b|≦1 to find a holomorphic f(z) from D to D?

Comment: Well, yes (if $a ≠ 0$), since then for $\lvert z \rvert < 1$, you’d have $\lvert f(z) \rvert ≤ \lvert az \rvert + \lvert b\rvert < \lvert a \rvert + \lvert b \rvert ≤ 1$. But this doesn’t help you here, because such an $f$ has $f’ = a$, so condition “$f’(3/4) = 1$” forces $a = 1$, and $\lvert a \rvert + \lvert b \rvert ≤ 1$ then forces $b = 0$, so $f = \mathrm{id}$, but that doesn’t do the trick with ”$f(1/2) = -1/2$”.

Comment: k.stm..See my edit.As u said "it doesn't do the trick".Doesn't it mean that such function can never exist?

Comment: I’m not sure, it might help to check out Schwarz Lemma and the characterization of automorphisms of the unit disc (which are certain Möbius transformations).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are wrong because $f$ does not map $D$ to $D$, because the codomain of $f$ is not equal to $D$. For example, $f\left(-\frac12\right) =-\frac{3}{2}$ which is not an element of $D$.

Comment: thanks..5xum..Will the answer be Yes if f maps unit disc to any other disc with unit radius?

Comment: @mathlover I don't understand your comment. What is the question?

Comment: I mean Is it correct to say that f(z)=z-1 maps {z€C:|z|≦1} to {z€C:|z-a|≦1} where a=1?

Comment: @mathlover Yes, it does. But that's far from the answer to your original question.